# getting error:- Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ocijdbc11 in java.library.path

Tags: java, jdbc

the ocijdbc file is present in the specified path

> C:\app\debpratim1\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\ocijdbc11.dll

but i am getting run time error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   ocijdbc11 in java.library.path

```
import java.sql.*;

import java.util.*;

class b1

{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception

    {
      System.setProperty("java.library.path",

       "C:/app/debpratim1/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/BIN/ocijdbc11.dll");

        Properties p1 = new Properties();

        p1.setProperty("user","scott");

        p1.setProperty("password","tiger");

        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver ob = new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();

        Connection con1 = ob.connect("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl",p1);//this is working

        Connection con2 = ob.connect("jdbc:oracle:oci:@localhost:1521:orcl",p1);//this is not working

        System.out.println(con1);

        System.out.println(con2);

        con1.close();

        con2.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Use the thin driver unless you MUST use the thick one.

Comment: "the ocijdbc file is present in the specified path": where is this path specified?

Comment: You have to add the path to your dll to the library path at runtime. The JVM can't just find it on it's own. See http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/

Comment: @AndréStannek i am using this code but the error is same System.setProperty("java.library.path", "C:/app/debpratim1/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/BIN/ocijdbc11.dll");

Comment: The path should be a folder name, or semicolon-separated list of folder names, not a filename.

Comment: @LukeWoodward is right. Change the path to `"C:/app/debpratim1/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/BIN/"`